# If $f(x)=0,\,g(x)=\sin(x)\,$ and $h(x)=e^x$ is setting $c_1=k\neq0, c_2=0$ and $c_3=0$ a non trivial linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given these $3$ functions, $f(x)=0,\;g(x)=\sin(x)$ and $h(x)=e^x\,,$ I have to find a non-trivial linear combination, that is, three constants that makes the combination of this functions equal to $0$.
$$
c_1\cdot{0}+c_2\cdot{\sin(x)+c_3\cdot{e^x}}=0
$$

The doubt here is with the definition of **non-trivial** linear combination, which as I understand, means that *not all* the constants are $0$.

That means that in this example I can put $c_1=1, c_2=0$ and $c_3=0$ but is this a non-trivial linear combination?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct +1. Minor correction -- in English, it's  usually called a "linear combination" (whereas in Spanish it's combinación lineal :-)